# Must I use viscoplastic model to fit the thermoplastic material

Tags: simulation, plastic, abaqus, elastic-modulus

I need to do the simulation with a specified material. It is known as a thermoplastic.
During the simulation, I need to define the material property.
I need to choose whether it is viscoplastic or viscoelasticity model.
I'm wondering whether the problem I want to model is truly visco-plastic (as it is thermo**plastic** material)
Or I can choose a viscoelastic model with considering the permanent deformation after sufficient relaxation time?

Comment: Is the thermoplastic being used above or below its glass transition temperature? How about its melting temperature?

Comment: The choice of material model depends on what you want to simulate.   For instance, linear elastic models will suffice if all you want is to find the small-strain stresses in a part.  Could you provide more detail on what you want to simulate?

Comment: @Chemomechanics.  It is above the glass transition temperature but far below the melting temperature.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscoplasticity#Perfectly_viscoplastic_solid_(Norton-Hoff_model)) (namely, the exponent value in the Norton-Hoff model) for one way to distinguish viscoplasticity from viscoelasticity in an idealized model.